# How can I add margins to label for a checkbox in CSS where checkbox is hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a long list of checkboxes in HTML like this:

```
<input id='1' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='1'>Checkbox 1</label>
<input id='2' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='2'>Checkbox 2</label>
<input id='3' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='3'>Checkbox 3</label>
```

etc.

I also have this CSS, which styles the labels, hides the actual checkboxes and links labels and checkboxes so that clicking the label will check the checkbox.

```
    input[type=checkbox].tag-checkbox{
        display: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
        background-color: rgb(0, 48, 85);
        color: white;
    }
    label{
         padding: 5px 7px;

         border-radius: 10px;
         background-color: rgb(191, 203, 213);
         
         cursor: pointer;
     }
```

Since I have so many, I am displaying these horizontally. However, when they fall onto the next line the background colours of the labels overlap. No matter where I put it in the CSS, I can not set vertical margins for the labels. Other questions have solution for the checkboxes, but I have these hidden.

Here it is in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dkprqu3b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your labels. This way, they'll behave more like blocks instead of lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, it is enough to use `flex` with the `flex-wrap: wrap` rule.

```css
input[type=checkbox].tag-checkbox{
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  background-color: rgb(0, 48, 85);
  color: white;
}
label{
  padding: 5px 7px;

  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(191, 203, 213);

  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.checkbox_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox_content">
  <input id='1' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='1'>Checkbox 1</label>
  <input id='2' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='2'>Checkbox 2</label>
  <input id='3' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='3'>Checkbox 3</label>
  <input id='4' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='4'>Checkbox 4</label>
  <input id='5' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='5'>Checkbox 5</label>
  <input id='6' class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox"'><label for='6'>Checkbox 6</label>
</div>
```